# Cannot import tensorflow in vscode

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

[image]
I have installed tensorflow in a virtual environment and can import Tensorflow in jupyter notebook or terminal. I am now learning to use VScode, so I try to launch it in the jupyter notebook within the VScode, but Tensorflow cannot be imported.

It shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow', but I have installed it and it can be used in the terminal or jupyternotebook.

I also tried to define the path of the python interpreter, but it did not work. Could someone help me out? Tons of thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

This works for me.

```
pip --version

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. Thanks all the same.

Comment: I found many people having the same issue as me. It is due to different python versions existing in the laptop. Firstly, I checked "sys.executable" in terminal and jupyter notebook and found the python used were different. Then, this is the solution working for me. https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1524

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **python 3.11.x** and **Win 11** then is working fine when I've imported as this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense 
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM as LSTM_keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
```

bye

Answer (score 0):

*Windows 10, python 3.10, tensorflow-gpu 2.10 installed in a V310_TF virtual environment.*

I specifically selected the good interpreter in VsCode `CTRL+SHIFT+P > Python: clear workspace interpreter settings`  `(CTRL+SHIFT+P) > Select interpreter ...` . The status bar at the bottom was updated accordingly pointing to V310_TF.

However, VsCode was still pointing to another interpreter in another virtual environment that i used the same day. I discovered it using

```
import sys
sys.executable
>>...\\v311_ANOTHER_ENV\\Scripts\\python.exe'
```

So the powershell instance in VsCode was not pointing where it was intended.

I restarted VsCode and it solved the problem.